# An undefined reference to error occurs when running Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, netcdf

I'm trying to use netCDF using Fortran, but I keep getting the following error.

```
PROGRAM net1
        use netcdf

        IMPLICIT NONE

        CHARACTER(len = 256) :: fi
        REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: T2(:,:,:)

        INTEGER :: dx, dy
        INTEGER :: ncid, varid
        INTEGER :: start(3), cou(3)

        fi = "wrfout_d10_2016-10-06_00.nc"
        dx = 209
        dy = 209

        call check(nf90_open(fi, NF90_NOWRITE, ncid), "opening T2 file")
        call check(nf90_inq_varid(ncid, "T2", varid), "getting T2 varid")

        allocate(T2(0, dx, dy))
        start = [0, 0, 0]
        cou   = [0, dx, dy]

        WRITE(*, *) "Reading Grid T2"
        call check(nf90_get_var(ncid, varid, T2, start = start, count = cou), "reading T2")
        WRITE(*, *) "T2 : ", sum(T2) / size(T2)

        call check(nf90_close(ncid), "closing T2 file")
        deallocate(T2)
END PROGRAM



gfortran net1.f90 -I/home/lsh/WRF/Library/include -L/home/lsh/WRF/Library/lib -lnetcdff -L/home/lsh/WRF/Library/lib -lnetcdf -ldl -lm -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz



/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccrMu0aM.o: in function `MAIN__':
net1.f90:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `check_'
/usr/bin/ld: net1.f90:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `check_'
/usr/bin/ld: net1.f90:(.text+0x5ca): undefined reference to `check_'
/usr/bin/ld: net1.f90:(.text+0x749): undefined reference to `check_'
```

The first part is the Fortran code that I made, the second part is the command that I executed, and the last part is the error that occurred

I don't know how to solve it

Comment: SUBROUTINE check(status, msg)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: status
    CHARACTER(*), INTENT(IN) :: msg

    IF (status /= 0) THEN
        WRITE(*, *) "Error: ", msg
        STOP
    END IF
END SUBROUTINE check

Comment: Thank you. There was a subroutine in the reference, but I should have added it

Comment: upvote the comment or answer if its helps you